# Convert vector of 0 and 1 to binary vector in R

Tags: r

It is quite surprise to me that I could not find a ready answer for this question on stackoverflow.

In R, I have a vector of `0` and `1`, and I want to convert it to binary vector, with `0` becomes `F` and `1` becomes `T`.

How could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: `as.logical(c(0,1,1,0))`.

Answer (score 5):

My comment should have been an answer. You can just do:

```
as.logical(c(0,1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `!!`:

```
rep(0:1, 5)
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

!!rep(0:1, 5)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

All 0s will be converted to `FALSE`, any other numeric to `TRUE`.

Comment: This is technically correct but in my opinion much less readable than using `as.logical`, as joran commented above.

Comment: R is not JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very much for all answers. Is it possible if instead of 0 and 1, I have a vector of ``-1`` and ``1``, and want to convert ``-1`` to ``F`` and ``1`` to ``T``?

Comment: `x <- rep(c(-1, 1), 5); x==1` is fine then: all 1s are TRUE; anything else, eg. -1 or 0, is FALSE

Answer (score 1):

We can use `!=`

```
c(0,1,1,0)!=0
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object size in memory is important (TRUE or FALSE are 56 bits size) a good option is the bit package, that can turn TRUE or FALSE values in a vector in to a 1 bit values vector.